# Force DOM changes before continuing Javascript function (for testing purposes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I'm trying to write some javascript unit tests (using QUnit).  In particular, I want to test various user actions, which I've been doing with `jQuery.simulate()` from jQueryUI (I think).

The issue is, of course, that these changes/events happen after the function ends because Javascript is single-threaded.

```
$("#myTextBox").focus().is(":focus") // returns false;
```

So, what I've been doing (and I know this is a really ugly solution) is running my tests with a series of Promises and `setTimeout()`:

```
var giveItASec = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve();
        });
    });
}

test("My test", function (assert) {
    var done = assert.async();
    Promise.resolve().then(function () {
        // do some assertions
        // DOM Manipulation
        return giveItASec();
    }).then(function () { 
        // more assertions about the DOM
        // repeat pattern as needed

        done();
    });
});
```

All the nested anonymous functions are giving me a headache, not to mention really slow down productivity, just from the sheer amount of typing.

There really must be a better async-to-sync pattern in javascript, right?  Please?

Comment: `$('input').focus().is(":focus")` runs fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/6pvvcx93/

Comment: Have you tried this [suggestion](http://qunitjs.com/cookbook/#testing-user-actions) from QUnit?